# Integration returning required y value for predefined area

Tags: matlab, area, numerical-integration

Given the following:

- Time series with `x` (time [s]) and `y` (here discharge [m³/s])
- Value `V1` (same units integrated `y`), smaller than the integral over all of `x`. In this case a small volume [m³].

I would like to calculate:

- The `y` value `y_V1` such that the integral between the line `y = y_V1` and the curve `y` equals `V1`.

  The following plot shows this, the orange region is `V1`, I want the circled value on the `y` axis:

  [image: Find corrsponding y]
- The `V1` must be placed around the peak.

I think this must be an iterative process, where also a the fitting criteria (and the degree of exactness) must be set by the user.

Until now, I haven't found a way to start; besides the pure integration.

The idea is to specify an area. The y value left and right of the peak which envelops this area should be calculated.

---

**Edit**

This is the result, if the accepted answer is applied.

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by decreasing some `y` value until your area target is met. See the comments below for details.

```
% Input data
x = 0:0.01:pi;
y = sin(x);

target = 1;     % Target area

yi = max( y );  % Initialise yi to be max possible y
dy = 0.001;     % Step change in yi

Ai = 0;         % Area each iteration
thresh = 0;     % Threshold for stopping loop
while target - Ai > thresh && yi >= min(y)
    yi = yi - dy;
    ix = y >= yi;
    % Approximate integral above the line
    Ai = trapz( x(ix), y(ix) - yi ); 
end

% Plot
figure(1); clf; hold on
plot( x, y );
patch( x(ix), y(ix), [1,0.5,0.5], 'facealpha', 0.5 );
plot( x, ones(size(x))*yi, '--', 'linewidth', 2 )
xlim( [min(x),max(x)] )
```

Output:

[image: plot]

Comment: Great! Great! Great!
It does the job and with your comments I understand the structure. Now I can develop it further to my specific needs.

For the result for my data, check the edited question.

Comment: Unclear is only:

`ix = y >= yi;`

What happens here? 
It's cool, that the result is a logical, but how does this come ?

Comment: @Ferdi `ix` is just an array, the same size as `y`, which is true when the condition `y>=yi` is true. Here `yi` is a scalar for the current minimum `y` value. Then we can use `ix` as the logical indexing array for the region we're interested in. Perhaps more clear (but equivalent) is `ix = (y>=yi)`.

Comment: How to avoid wrong interpolation, if there are several peaks? I'm one interested in the biggest, so to say I only need only the first block of true values in `ix`. I'm looking for an exit to `ix = y>=yi`. As soon as `ix` is not true where it was true before, I want to stop.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ferdi you can look for `[0, diff(ix)] < 1`, that's when it changes from true to false. If you need more help then have a go, produce a [mcve] and ask a new question.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I coldn't figure it out how to stop the trapz function to integrate into the next peak.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56025930/trapz-function-only-for-limited-x-range ist where I formulated  a new question