# trapz function only for limited x range

Tags: matlab, area, numerical-integration

I want to integrate time series data (of a river wave) which has certain peaks, but I only need the integral for the highest peak.

I have a predefined area which the integral should satisfy, and I change a y-axis threshold to achieve this area.

This previous question describes the original problem in more detail: [Integration returning required y value for predefined area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431457/integration-returning-required-y-value-for-predefined-area/55432603?noredirect=1#comment98568971_55432603).
With help of [Wolfie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/wolfie), code was developed to answer that.

**The problem is now that I also integrate over other peaks, when I don't want to**.

The code so far:

```
x = Q(:,1); %
y = Q(:,2); %

target = 17.4e+06;  % Target area = Polder Volume

yi = max( y );      % Initialise yi to be max possible y
dy = 10;            % Step change in yi

Ai = 0;             % Area first iteration
thresh = 10000;     % Threshold for stopping loop
while target - Ai > thresh && yi >= min(y)
    yi = yi - dy;
    ix = y >= yi;
    % Approximate integral above the line
    Ai = trapz( x(ix), y(ix) - yi );
end
figure(e); clf; hold on

plot( x, y );
patch( x(ix), y(ix), [1,0.5,0.5], 'facealpha', 0.5 );
plot( x, ones(size(x))*yi, '--', 'linewidth', 2 )
xlim( [min(x),max(x)] )
```

Results in:

[image: integral]

If applied to Data with several peaks.

**In summary:**

How can I make sure only the biggest peak is cut off by the integral? 
How can I prevent `Ai` from including to other peaks and still come close to the target?

Comment: One thing to consider: can you assume that the *highest* peak is also the biggest, or do you not care? You could have a lower peak which is broader, and would satisfy the integral for a higher `yi`.

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for considering this. It is about the **highest**. 
In this case (see picture above). I don't want the end of the time series (on the very right to be included). But the yet the second highest should be included if the volume allows this. After working on different cases, i came to the conclusing that fully automatic postprocessing isn't useful here. A visual expert judgement is needed. Therefore I will delete the question (it doesn't help the community) as soon as I see, that you noticed my comment. Give me a short comment and thanks.

Comment: thanks for the update, try and consider when manually processing data what criteria you're using to discard regions. In future, you can probably formalise that thinking to help you automate analysis.

Comment: As I understand the problem, you want the second peak next to the big guy as long as there's still area to fill, but not the peak out at the right? How would you know not to go a bit lower on the main peak but to reach over to the next? Is that based on the width of the base of the first peak vs. the span to the tip of the second one at that point?

Comment: @Wick  Thanks for your interest. You understand the problem correctly. 
The x axe is the time in seconds. I'm not interested in the one on the far right, since the time span of ~ 1 Mio s is quite long for my application.
I'm good with the found solution.